# How to write a list containing key and another list as value into CSV file per column in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

can someone please help me?

I have a list:

```
list = [('ac', [1, 1]), ('alex.miller', [1, 2]), ('blossom', [2, 3])]
```

I want to write it into CSV file to look like this:

ac,1,1

alex.miller,1,2

blossom,2,3

So far I tried (also tried to split the integer list, convert it to string and concatenate it back with row[0] but with no success, the output was like a,c,1,1 a,l,e,x,.,m etc.):

```
with open(r"user_statistics.csv", "a+") as csvfile_user:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile_user)
  for row in list:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

But the output is:

ac,"[1, 1]"

alex.miller,"[1, 2]"

blossom,"[2, 3]"

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpack the list with the values

```
writer.writerow((row[0], *row[1]))
```

Output:

```
ac,1,1

alex.miller,1,2

blossom,2,3
```

As a side note, don't use built in `list` as a variable name.

Comment: thank you very much :) I didn't use the list variable name in actual code, I just put it there, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert what you have into list of flat tuples or flat list before feeding into `writerow`, for example

```
my_list = [('ac', [1, 1]), ('alex.miller', [1, 2]), ('blossom', [2, 3])] 
my_list = [(i[0],*i[1]) for i in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

output

```
[('ac', 1, 1), ('alex.miller', 1, 2), ('blossom', 2, 3)]
```

Explanation: I used `list` comprehension and argument unpacking to convert tuples with str and list into flat tuples

As side note: do not use `list` as variable name, as it does overshadow built-in `list`.

Comment: thank you very much :) I didn't use the list variable name in actual code, I just put it there, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

if using pandas is acceptable, then try this:

```
import pandas as pd
ls = [('ac', [1, 1]), ('alex.miller', [1, 2]), ('blossom', [2, 3])]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['A', 'B'])

# split the list into new columns
df[['C','D']] = pd.DataFrame(df['B'].tolist(), index= df.index)

# drop that original list columns
df.drop('B', axis=1, inplace=True)
# finally convert to csv file
df.to_csv('mycsv.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks, I am not familiar with pandas but I will definitely check it because it looks interesting